# Does converge in distribution imply limit being finite almost surely?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

If I have a sequence of random variable $x_n$ converge in distribution to a standard normal random variable, i.e.,

$$x_n\overset{d}{\to}N(0,1)$$

Does the following hold? Why or why not?

$$p(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n<\infty)=1$$

---

### Edited on 02/22/2018

More specifically, think about $x_n=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{I}$ where $y_i$'s are i.i.d. rv with zero mean and variance 1. By CLT you would have

$$x_n\overset{d}{\to}N(0,1)$$

The reason that I care about $p(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n<\infty)=1$ is because that I am trying to find the limit of the following integral

$$\int f_n(t,x_n) dt$$

and I can show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(t,x_n)=f_{0}(t, x_n)$ and $f_{0}(t,x_n)$ is integrable no matter what $x_n$ is. I want to apply DCT and I have been able to show that for sufficiently large $n$,

$$f_n(t,x_n)<g(t)\exp\{x_n\},$$

where $g(t)$ is integrable. Hence it seems to me that as long as $\int g(t)\exp\{x_n\} dt<\infty$ holds almost surely I can apply DCT.

Comment: There is no guarantee that this probability makes any sense.

Comment: In fact, just in general, when thinking about convergence in distribution, it is usually best to assume that your random variables are not even defined on the same probability space, so that you are not tempted to do absurd things like adding them or taking pointwise limits of them.

Comment: Hi @Ian, thanks for the comment. I do not get it why this probability could make no sense. I have added more context, and I was wondering if you still think the probability makes no sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $X_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i$ where $Y_i$ are i.i.d. and have zero mean and unit variance, then $X_n$ does not converge in distribution to $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. In fact, the law of iterated logarithm tells that $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{X_n}{\sqrt{2n\log\log n}} = 1$$ almost surely (and of course the analogous statement for liminf). And what the classical CLT asserts is that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}X_n \stackrel{d}{\to} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thx, it was a typo. And thanks for bringing up the law of iterated logarithm!

Comment: No problem. Indeed, LIL tells that (with the corrected definition of $x_n$) we still have $\varlimsup \frac{x_n}{\sqrt{2\log\log n}} = 1$ and hence $x_n$ is almost surely unbounded.

Comment: @Bayesric In general convergence in distribution does not imply that the random variables in the sequence are even defined on the same probability space. If they are not, then the a.s. limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Law of Iterated Logarithm:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm
show that the opposite is true: $P\{\limsup x_n =\infty\} =1$